# Imprimir mes abreviado en Python

Tags: python, date, datetime

¿Cómo puedo imprimir el nombre del mes abreviado en python usando datetime?

Probé esto:

```
fecha= datetime.now()
print(f"Fecha:{fecha.hour}:{fecha.minute}   {fecha.day}/{fecha.month}/{fecha.year}");
input()
```

Answer (score 6):

No necesitas extraer los campos para imprimirlos como haces en el ejemplo de la pregunta. Las fechas `datetime` tienen el método `.strftime()` al cual se le pasa una cadena de formato [con una sintaxis especial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) para especificar qué partes de la fecha y en qué orden las quieres.

La cadena de formato para extraer el nombre del mes abreviado es `"%b"`, por lo que la siguiente línea mostraría la fecha en el formato que querías:

```
from datetime import datetime
fecha= datetime.now()
print(fecha.strftime("%H:%M %d/%b/%Y"))
```

```html
08:37 03/Dec/2018
```

Como ves el nombre del mes sale en inglés por defecto. Si quieres que salga en otro idioma puedes cambiar el `locale`. Por ejemplo, para que salga en español:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, ("es_ES", "UTF-8"))
print(fecha.strftime("%H:%M %d/%b/%Y"))
```

```html
08:40 03/dic/2018
```

Comment: Esta solución es buena pero me generaba un error en Windows al tratar de hacer logging. Este error se elimina usando "locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "es-ES").

Answer (score 4):

Lo que puedes hacer, es guardarte un diccionario que la clave sea el mes del año y el valor el mes.

```
#Mes completo, luego lo recortamos. Es por si lo necesitas despues
mesesDic = {
    "01":'Enero',
    "02":'Febrero',
    "03":'Marzo',
    "04":'Abril',
    "05":'Mayo',
    "06":'Junio',
    "07":'Julio',
    "08":'Agosto',
    "09":'Septiembre',
    "10":'Octubre',
    "11":'Noviembre',
    "12":'Diciembre'
}
```

Luego simplemente le tienes que pasar el año y obtendras el mes.

```
#Obtenemos el numero del mes actual.
mes = datetime.datetime.now().month
#Nos quedamos con los primero 3 caracteres
print(mesesDic[str(mes)][:3])
```

## UPDATE

Hay una manera de hacerlo mucho mas sencilla y automática usando el modulo `calendar` de python.

Ejemplo: Obtener todos los días de la semana abreviados usando el método [day_abbr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.day_abbr)

```
import calendar
print(list(calendar.day_abbr))
```

Si queremos obtener el mes completo entonces tenemos el método [day_name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.day_name)

```
import calendar
print(list(calendar.day_name))
```

Ambos métodos nos permite acceder a una position especifica que representa un día de la semana, por ejemplo si queremos saber que día es el índice numero 3

```
import calendar
print(calendar.day_name[3]) # Jueves
```

> Por defecto los valores estarán en el idioma definido por el sistema, para cambiarlos es necesario el uso del modulo **locale**.

> Si se implementa con django, se puede hacer uso de la función **_** para traducir los días

Answer (score 1):

¡Usa el módulo [`arrow`](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)!

```
>>> arrow.utcnow().format('MMM', locale='es')
'nov'
>>> arrow.utcnow().format('MMMM', locale='es')
'noviembre
```

Usando [`format()`](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#format) y los códigos ([supported tokens](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#supported-tokens)) puedes definir qué quieres ver. En este caso, yo usé:

- `MMM` para nombre abreviado del mes
- `MMMM` para nombre completo del mes

Y luego le defino el locale en castellano para que aparezca en este idioma.

También puedes usar [`humanize()`](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#humanize):

```
>>> arrow.Arrow(2019,12,31).humanize()
'11 months ago'

>>> arrow.Arrow(2019,12,31).humanize(locale='es')
'hace 11 meses'
```